# Cloud Functions continuously executing after timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a firestore app with a cloud function that triggers off a cronjob. 
The cloud function takes a long time and pulls a large amount of data. I've set the memory limit of my function to 2Gb and the timeout to 540 second and ***Retry on failure*** is **NOT** checked.

The cloud function essentially looks like this:

```
export const fetchEpisodesCronJob = pubsub
   .topic('daily-tick')
   .onPublish(() => {
       console.log(`TIMING - Before Fetches ${rssFeeds.length} feeds`, new Date())

   return Promise.map(
      rssFeeds.map(rssFeed => rssFeed.url),
      url => fetch(url).catch(e => e).then(addFeedToDB), // <-- This can take a long time
      {
           concurrency: 4
      }
    ).catch(e => {
       console.warn('Error fetching feeds', e);
    })
})
```

What I see in the logs however is this (Continues indefinitely): 
[image]

As you can see the function is being finished with a status *timeout* however it's starting right back up again. What's weird is I've specified a 540 second limit however the timeout comes in at a consistent 5 minute mark. Also note I checked the cloud console and I manually spun off the last cronjob pubsub at 10:00AM yet you can see multiple pubsub triggers since then. (So I believe the cronjob is setup fine)

Also I get consistent errors repeating in the console:

[image]

My question is how do I prevent the cloud function from re-executing when it's already been killed due to a timeout. Is this a bug or do I need to explicitly set a kill statement somewhere.

Thanks!

Comment: Turns out there's a backend bug in Cloud Functions that happens when a function is created with the default timeout but later increased that is causing this. A fix is being worked on and will hopefully address the issue soon.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the quick response @MichaelBleigh. So in essence this should happen every time I increase the default timeout? Is there a current workaround right now or should I just sit tight? My function definitely requires more than 60 seconds to complete.

Comment: It *might* only happen for PubSub functions (and other function types will be unaffected). I believe the fix is imminent, so you might just be able to sit tight.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh do you know if there is an open issue for this? I am running into something similar (not sure if it's the same) and am wondering if it's related. Thank you.

Comment: Since this is from 2018, I very much doubt it's the same issue :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is a bug with firebase. According to @MichaelBleigh

> Turns out there's a backend bug in Cloud Functions that happens when a function is created with the default timeout but later increased that is causing this. A fix is being worked on and will hopefully address the issue soon.

If you're reading this in between now and when the bug is fixed though I found that the function will be triggered again ever 300 seconds. So an immediate work around for me is to set the timeout for 250 seconds and keep the time complexity of the function as minimal as possible. This may mean increasing the memory usage for the time being.

Comment: Just FYI - this bug has been impacting me currently, so not sure if it was ever properly fixed. I disabled my app engine cron job, which was triggering the pub/sub function, and the function still continued to repeat at 4 - 8 minute intervals (calling 3 - 8 times). I had to re-deploy my project. I am going to attempt to switch to [schedule functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) methodology to see if that works better. Maybe @MichaelBleigh can weigh in.